# Trying to get areas to work in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a new MVC3 project setup, and I added a folder inside my controller named "area1".

I then put my controller inside that folder named abc.cs:

```
public class abc : Controller
{
        //
        // GET: /abc/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("abc index");
    }

}


public class MyAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "My Area"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "abc",
            "area1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "abc", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        // And so on ...
    }
}
```

Now when I go to:

`/area1/abc/index`

I get an error page.

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

I put a breakpoint in the RegisterArea method and it doesn't get called.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Other Few questions:

1. can I put my areas folder and controller code anywhere in the project, or does it have to be inside the main controllers folder?
2. can I have my views in my areas folder also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> and I added a folder inside my controller named "area1".

Since your controller is a class, it doesn't make sense to add a folder to it.

The process to create an area goes something like this:

1. In Visual Studio, right click on the project root, and select `Add|Area`
2. Enter the name for the area - `Area1` or what have you.
3. VS will create `~/areas/area1`, and add the Views, Controllers and Models folders.
4. Add, for instance, `IndexController.cs` to the Areas1/Controllers folder.
5. Add a view, "Index.cshtml", to the Area1/Views folder
6. Rebuild the solution.
7. Open http://localhosdt/area1/index in your browser, and you should see your view.

Comment: sorry I meant I added the folder in /controllers, so its /controllers/area1/

Comment: that's backwards. The controller belongs in`~/areas/area1/controllers/`, views in `~/areas/area1/views`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The folder structure that you should use is:

```
- Project -
    Areas
        < Area Name >
            Controllers
                MyController.cs
            Models
                MyModel.cs
            Views
                etc.
```

Why don't you just use the Add Area context-menu option?

In answer to your question about where you can put your code, there's an amount of flexibility, but a lot of the functionality of ASP.NET MVC relies on convention over configuration. Put the code where MVC wants it and you'll make your like much easier.

Comment: +1 "Why don't you just use the Add Area context-menu option?"